# How to set fixed axis intervals with Qt/QwtPlot?

Tags: c++, user-interface, qt, plot, qwt

I want to have a plotting widget in my Qt application. Qwt provides such a widget with QwtPlot. However, I can't find any way to only display a certain part of the complete range of my data.

Specifically, I want to display spectrums with a frequency range from 0 to 2^14. For the GUI however, only the audible range from ~20-20k Hz is of significance, so I only want to display that part.
Do you know of any way of telling QwtPlot to do that?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple answer: Use QwtPlot::setAxisScale().

sorry for answering my own question.

Comment: It's all right to answer your own questions. You can mark it as your own answer after some time.